# Changing class of same id

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a method to change the class of the same id's. I have a table with multiple rows and some parent-child 'rows'. Thus when clicked on the parent, the class of the child has to change aswell. I have the following code:

```
function FormTRClick(event, ctrl) {
   if (event.target.tagName == 'TD') {
       if (document.getElementById('chk' + ctrl).checked == true) {
           document.getElementById('chk' + ctrl).checked = false;
           document.getElementById('row' + ctrl).className = "invoice-tr-standard";
       } else {
           document.getElementById('chk' + ctrl).checked = true;
           document.getElementById('row' + ctrl).className = "invoice-tr-clicked";
       }
   }
}
```

This script is called by: `<tr class='invoice-tr-standard' id='row1' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '1')">` and each parent has a new ID (so parent + child carry the same ID).

How can I do this? Do I have to put the elements into an array and then loop through them to give them the proper classname? Or is there any other way todo so?

Thanks.

**Update**

I have a table, with multiple rows. I have it like this:

```
row1 Parent
  row1 Child
  row1 Child
row2 Parent
  row2 Child
row3 Parent
row4 Parent
  row4 Child
```

I want the `className` of **all** row1 (or row2, depends on which one has been clicked on) to be changed to `invoice-tr-clicked` when clicked on the `<tr>` as seen above.

So, when clicked on a 'parent' the 'child' rows (since they share the same ID) have to have their classnames changed into `invoice-tr-clicked` or `invoice-tr-standard` depending on their current style.

**HTML code as from the page**

```
<tr class='invoice-tr-standard' id='row1' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '1')"><td><input type='checkbox' name='strFormFactuur[]' value='19796' id='chk1'>&nbsp;<img src='../images/link.png' border='0'></td>    
    <td>€ <input type='text' value='19.001' id='fltFormTextBedrag1'> <img src='../images/b_save.png' border='0' height='13px' style='cursor: pointer;'></td>    
</tr>
<tr class='invoice-tr-standard' id='row1' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '1')"><td></td>    
    <td>€ <input type='text' name='FormTextFltBedrag' value='19.000'> <img src='../images/b_save.png' border='0' height='13px' style='cursor: pointer;'></td>
</tr>
<tr class='invoice-tr-standard' id='row1' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '1')"><td></td>    
    <td>€ <input type='text' name='FormTextFltBedrag' value='19.000'> <img src='../images/b_save.png' border='0' height='13px' style='cursor: pointer;'></td>    
</tr>
<tr class='invoice-tr-standard' id='row2' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '2')"><td><input type='checkbox' name='strFormFactuur[]' value='19436' id='chk2'>&nbsp;<img src='../images/link.png' border='0'></td>    
    <td>€ <input type='text' value='61.280' id='fltFormTextBedrag4'> <img src='../images/b_save.png' border='0' height='13px' style='cursor: pointer;'></td>    
</tr>
<tr class='invoice-tr-standard' id='row2' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '2')"><td></td>    
    <td>€ <input type='text' name='FormTextFltBedrag' value='61.280'> <img src='../images/b_save.png' border='0' height='13px' style='cursor: pointer;'></td>    
</tr>
<tr class='invoice-tr-standard' id='row3' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '3')"><td><input type='checkbox' name='strFormFactuur[]' value='19718' id='chk3'></td>    
    <td>€ <input type='text' value='162.340' id='fltFormTextBedrag6'> <img src='../images/b_save.png' border='0' height='13px' style='cursor: pointer;'></td>    
</tr>
<tr class='invoice-tr-standard' id='row3' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '3')"><td></td>    
    <td>€ <input type='text' name='FormTextFltBedrag' value='162.340'> <img src='../images/b_save.png' border='0' height='13px' style='cursor: pointer;'></td>    
</tr>
```

Comment: Your sample HTML does not even contain `<td>`'s... :-?

Comment: I'm not sure what the extra value it would have been to add `<td>`'s. It doesn't change the question nor it adds value.

Comment: Believe it or not, the structure of the document determines the way to traverse it.

Comment: As already said by W. Mursh, you can't have duplicate ids. You can though access one element's childs with javascript. Hence you don't need to set child's id to match its parent id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a common mistake, but `id` attributes must *always* be unique. There cannot be two elements with the same `id` value. You are not guaranteed anything to work if you are using the same id on multiple elements.

From: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/id

> The most important aspect of the id attribute is that it must be
>   absolutely unique. Unlike the class attribute, which may apply the
>   same value to many elements in a page, an id that’s applied to an
>   element must not match an id used anywhere else on the same page.

I know this doesn't really answer your question, but I don't understand what your question is, it may be completely based on incorrect usage of HTML.

Comment: Well, I need to change the class of all `<tr>`'s with the `id` __row1__. Doing this through classes wouldn't work obviously. And the `id` is somewhat unique, to a certain degree.

Comment: @Devator "unique" is not a relative term. Either you have more than one element with the same ID or you don't.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing the HTML, is every id unique or not? It looks like maybe you're using 2 ids per number: `row1` and `chk1`. If so, and no two ids are exactly the same, then that is correct usage and I apologize. In the meantime, why don't you show us the HTML output? Or even just explain your goal, it's very hard to tell.

Comment: "Well, I need to change the class of **all** <tr>'s with the id row1." - That is the problem, there should only be one of those. Or did you really mean that you want to change all `<td>`'s that belong to `<tr id="row1">`? The update you posted doesn't clear up much because it's not HTML, it's a text representation. Post actual code.

Comment: OK, you've confirmed my suspicion. You will need to rethink your strategy. It's not a *suggestion*, it is a specification. You cannot  duplicate ids and expect anything to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Give your rows two-part unique ids like this:

```
row1_1 Parent
  row1_2 Child
  row1_3 Child
row2_1 Parent
  row2_2 Child
row3_1 Parent
row4_1 Parent
  row4_2 Child
```

And change the class switch part of your code to:

```
var i = 1;
var element;
while( ( element = document.getElementById( 'chk' + ctrl + '_' + i ) ) !== null ) {
    if (element.checked == true) {
       element.checked = false;
       element.className = "invoice-tr-standard";
    } else {
       element.checked = true;
       element.className = "invoice-tr-clicked";
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: This would work yes, but I already shifted over my entire code on those classes, so not bothering to switch back unless for some reason it's necessary. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @Devator Well, searching for an element with a certain class name is always very slow compared to searching for an element with a unique id. I would never use class names to search for an element unless I don't have access to the HTML. It's your decision though :)

Comment: Fair enough, but in my script you have a table with parent and childs (which mean that the child doesn't have a checkbox). When clicked on the parent's checkbox the class of the parent and child have to be changed so their background color changes (so you can easily see they have been selected). But, there's no way to know what a child is of which parent. That's why I couldn't have this unique numbers. Ofcourse with your method it might be possible, but then you would still have to look through all id's and if one of them match partially with the parent, change the class.

Comment: @Devator I'm having a little hard time understanding why you need to know which child is of which parent, when the parent is clicked you can go through all children and the parent itself (you always know that ids ending with 1 are parents) with the code in my answer and change their class. But if you need to know the parent's id anyway this is how: `parentId = childId.substr( 0, childId.indexOf( '_' ) + 1 ) + '1'`

Comment: Yes, in this case it would work. But what if you would press the invert all button (like in my other question), then you would loop through every row. I don't think that would do good to the loading time.

Comment: @Devator When you are inverting all checkboxes you are still searching for children of each checkbox by their class name which is much slower than searching for unique ids, it is not different at all from the situation here. I can't think of a single situation where using class names is better than using ids.