# Is there any way to optimise this code?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code which will invert all the checkboxes on my form. I have multiple elements (not just checkboxes but also  `<input type='text'>`'s) in it. The reason I need it to be optimised is because it takes about two to three seconds to select all the checkboxes (275 right now).

Here's my code:

```
function FormInverse() {
    var iCheckbox = 1; // Because there are multiple input elements, we need to distinquish the input element ID and the row id
    var FormLength = document.FormFacturen.elements.length;
    for (i=0; i < FormLength; i++) {
        var FormElementType = document.FormFacturen.elements[i].type;
        if (FormElementType == "checkbox") {
            var Elements = document.getElementsByClassName('row' + iCheckbox); // Alle elementen in de array zetten
            var iNumElements = Elements.length;
            for (iElement=0; iElement < iNumElements; iElement++) {
                if (document.FormFacturen[i].checked == true) {
                    Elements[iElement].className = "invoice-tr-standard row" + iCheckbox;
                } else {
                    Elements[iElement].className = "invoice-tr-clicked row" + iCheckbox;
                }
            }
            iCheckbox++;
            document.FormFacturen[i].checked = !document.FormFacturen[i].checked;
        }
    }   
}
```

And here is the `document.getElementsByClassName` function:

```
document.getElementsByClassName = function(cl) {
    var retnode = [];
    var myclass = new RegExp('\\b'+cl+'\\b');
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        var classes = elem[i].className;
        if (myclass.test(classes)) retnode.push(elem[i]);
    }
    return retnode;
};
```

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't leverage something like jQuery? This type of scripting is so much simpler in jQuery.

Comment: @Josh because I have never really worked with jQuery so I'm not experienced with it. If it end-result is that it's going to be faster, then it's ok.

Comment: I'd definitely check to see if the browser already implements `document.getElementsByClassName()` or the Selectors API and use these if they exist and fall back to your function if they don't. They are likely to be considerably faster.

Comment: This question should be moved to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using jQuery as well.

Try this:

Add a reference to jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
```

Use this code:

```
$(':checkbox').each( function() {
  $(this).attr('checked', !$(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

Edited:
Or use this to change the classes as well:

```
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
    var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
    if (checked) {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
        $(this).addClass('invoice-tr-clicked');
        $(this).removeClass('invoice-tr-standard');        
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
        $(this).addClass('invoice-tr-standard');
        $(this).removeClass('invoice-tr-clicked');
    }
});
```

Final version:

```
$('#FormFacturen :checkbox').each(function() {
    var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
    if (checked) {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass('invoice-tr-clicked');
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('invoice-tr-standard');        
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass('invoice-tr-standard');
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('invoice-tr-clicked');
    }
});
```

Comment: And how would I change the class then? See my first post from this line: `for (iElement=0; iElement < iNumElements; iElement++) {`

Comment: You could add this:

    $(':checkbox:checked').attr('class', 'invoice-tr-standard row');
    $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('class', 'invoice-tr-clicked row');

Comment: Thanks, but the row is normally passed through Javascript (`"invoice-tr-standard row" + iCheckbox;`) and I still need to keep that id `iCheckbox` send with it (it's different per row).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that one. Do you have the row + iCheckbox set already or is it only done in this function?

I updated the code, so that is does not change the row + iCheckbox class/

Comment: Thank you, that should work I guess. But how would I call this function? I have a simple `<td>` field with an `onClick` function on it which normally called the `FormInverse()` function.

Comment: Just add this code in the FormInverse() function and call it in the same way.

Comment: Ok well it work's semi. The class is changed but it needed to be the `<tr>`s class to be changed. Secondly it's inverting __all__ checkboxes while it should only invert those within 'FormFacturen' (my bad on that part for explaining). I didn't state it in my question so thanks for helping.

Comment: If it only should be in FormFacturen, you can use:

    $('#FormFacturen :checkbox')...

And to change the <tr> class, you could use:

    $(this).parents('tr').addClass(...)

Answer (score 2):

Each call to `getElementsByClassName` is expensive, and it is being called on each pass of your for loop.

In addition to @Geoff's suggestion, you could call `document.getElementsByTagName('input');` just *once*, instead of each time `getElementsByClassName` is called and cache the result for use within your loop.

That would require making a small modification to your `getElementsByClassName` function whereby it accepts an array of elements to search through.

```
document.getElementsByClassName = function(cl, eles) {
    var retnode = [];
    var myclass = new RegExp('\\b'+cl+'\\b');
    var len = eles.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var classes = eles[i].className;
        if (myclass.test(classes)) retnode.push(eles[i]);
    }
    return retnode;
};


function FormInverse() {
    // cache all inputs
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    ...
    // later
    var Elements = document.getElementsByClassName('row' + iCheckbox, inputs);
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. It's still slow. Maybe it's because I'm changing the tr class aswell?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into a library like JQuery.  It will handle this kind of thing well.

There are a lot of little things you can do to improve your code though.  First thing I notice is that your getElementsByClassName function is looping through ALL elements on your page every time you call it.  You could change this line:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

to just get the input elements:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Comment: Thank you, it has been reduced by 50% (but it's still a fat second - so it's still too slow to use).

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty much sure the bottleneck here is the `getElementsByClassName` function, the browser needs to re-scan the whole html each time to find your element. I suggest you give your elements a unique id `id="row1"`, `id="row2"`, ... instead of a unique class name and use `getElementById` which is much faster.

```
 var Elements = document.getElementsById('row' + iCheckbox);
```

Comment: I'm not able to use this method since my id's are not unique. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092421/changing-class-of-same-id) for more information about why I am not able to use this.

Comment: @Devator I posted an answer to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092421/changing-class-of-same-id/7107619#7107619) that will solve your problem here too.